# display multi line in as one line SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle column type is `VARCHAR2(300)` has text for all records multi lines I need to display it in one line for EX>

```
ID                         TEXT
--------------------------------------
1                       Hi this is
                        your numbaer
                        102458
---------------------------------------
2                      hi this is
                       your number
                       452187
```

Now I need to display text column as one line

```
ID                         TEXT
--------------------------------------
1                       Hi this is your numbaer  102458
---------------------------------------
2                      hi this is  your number 452187
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace line breaks with blanks supposedly. Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` for this.

What I often do is replace all blank space (no matter whether a single blank or tab, a group of blanks, line breaks, any combinbation thereof) with a single blank:

```
regexp_replace(col, '[[:space:]]+', ' ')
```

If you want to restrict this to control characters:

```
regexp_replace(col, '[[:cntrl:]]+', ' ')
```

Or only carriage return and line feed:

```
regexp_replace(col, '[' || chr(10) || chr(13) || ']+', ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks,  this one  regexp_replace(col, '[' || chr(10) || chr(13) || ']+', ' ') worked with me

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you may format column `TEXT` with sqlplus command by sufficient data length :

`SQL> col format text a100;`